# How to tell EF which link table to use?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EntityFramework with a link table and I have created a OnModelCreating that creates a link table called "RolePrivileges". But I have another dbcontext that uses the same database but with the relation the other way so I get this error:
`Invalid object name 'dbo.PrivilegeRoles'`

My Privilege class has a `public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }` property.

How can I tell EF that it's from RolePrivileges and not PrivilegeRoles?

**UPDATE**

*I have added some code, this a big project and I am using repository pattern and all that. This is just to show the error*

I have many projects, one for only generating the database that has all entities, migrations and all that.

in the dbcontext in this project I have

```
public class EasyhoursDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    ...
    public DbSet<Role> AccessRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Privilege> Privileges { get; set; }
    ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
            .HasMany(role => role.Privileges)
            .WithMany(p => p.AccessRoles)
            .Map(ap =>
            {
                ap.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
                ap.MapRightKey("PrivilegeId");
                ap.ToTable("RolePrivileges");
            });
        ...
    }
}

public class Role
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public virtual List<Privilege> Privileges { get; private set; } 
}

public class Privilege
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Role> AccessRoles { get; set; }
}
```

And then in another project I have a dbcontext that just contains this

```
public class RoleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public RoleDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Role> AccessRoles { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Privilege> Privileges { get; set; }
}

public class Privilege
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    ...

    [JsonIgnore]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Role> AccessRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public string Id { get; protected set; }

    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    public List<Privilege> Privileges { get; set; } = new List<Privilege>();
}
```

And here's an example where I get the error:

```
var db = new RoleDbContext();

var role = db.AccessRoles.FirstOrDefault(r => true);
var privilege = db.Privileges.FirstOrDefault(p => true);

role.Privileges.Add(privilege);

db.Entry(role).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

On save changes I get the error:

[image]

Running this exact same code, but with EasyhoursDbContext instead it works fine

**UPDATE**

I updated the RoleDbContext now to contain the exact same rule for the onmodelcreation as EasyhoursDbContext.

But now I'm getting this error:
`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.RolePrivileges'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.RolePrivileges'. The duplicate key value is (03fd67b6-277f-43f6-b276-5bafbdbe55af, A657a693-0961-Role-b86b-381261aApply).\r\nThe statement has been terminated.`

Comment: Multiple context issues aside, show your models and fluent code for the context in question.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Why don't you add fluent configuration to your `RoleDbContext` `OnModelCreating` like in `EasyhoursDbContext`?

Comment: tried it and it doesn't work. And isn't that only for the database generations like when using migrations? so it shouldn't do any difference either?

Comment: No, it's not just for migrations. It is used to build the internal model that EF uses when referring to that context and composing the SQL statements. Because that fluent code is lacking, it drops down to the defaults which is to use a table called PrivilegeRoles.

Comment: Ah, I can see that now, it was a different error i got. I updated the question with that error

Comment: That's a common duplicate key message - most likely the Role/Privilege combo already exists. Check for existence before adding.

Comment: If it's seeding code, look at [AddOrUpdate](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/)

Comment: ah, sorry, that was my mistake :P And thanks for the help. All I needed was to add that onmodelcreation to the RoleDbContext :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanna thank Steve Greene for helping me with finding the problem.

All I needed was to add OnModelCreation to my RolesDbContext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
    .HasMany(role => role.Privileges)
    .WithMany(p => p.AccessRoles)
    .Map(ap =>
    {
         ap.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
         ap.MapRightKey("PrivilegeId");
         ap.ToTable("RolePrivileges");
    });
```